# What is the degree of the differential equation $\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right| + \left|y\right| = 0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $$\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right| + \left|y\right| = 0$$ 
where $\left|\cdot\right|$ means the absolute value function. I have to find the degree of the above differential equation. Can I say the degree of this differential equation is not defined as it is not a polynomial in $y'$?

If we further solve it, we get $$\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right| = -\left|y\right|$$ Then taking square we get  $ \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{2}- y^{2} =0$ which has degree $2$.

Now can I say that the two differential equation are not same? So the degree of the first one is not defined. Am I right?

Comment: The vertical lines are absolute value bars, or am I misreading them?

Comment: yes absolute values ..

Comment: I don't see where is the point in trying to define the degree of that equation. Anyway, there is a mistake, it would be $$(y')^2+y^2=0$$ not $(y')^2-y^2=0$

Comment: ok then what is degree?

Comment: @Crostul If $|a| + |b| = 0$ then $a^2 = b^2$ so $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ is right. Anyway $|a| + |b| = 0$ also implies $|a| = 0$ and $|b| = 0$ so $y=0$ is the only solution here.

Comment: so you mean its degree is 2?

Comment: You can use `\left| ... \right|` to get nice looking absolute value bars that has the right size.

Comment: Unfortunately, the thoughtless upvotes for this question shows that MSE inhabitants behave like a herd of sheep and that mathematical awareness is low.

Comment: it will be very thanks full if you answer the question...

Comment: And, _most_ unfortunately, I've been one of those sheep in the herd :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. Let's do it nice and easy:
$$
\left|\frac{dy}{dx}\right| + \left|y\right| = 0
$$
Consider instead the simplified equation:
$$
\left|A\right| + \left|B\right| = 0
$$
Do you agree that this is exactly the same as:
$$
\begin{cases} A = 0 \\ B = 0 \end{cases}
$$
In your case, substitute:
$$
A = \frac{dy}{dx} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y = \mbox{constant} \\
B = y \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y = 0
$$
Therefore $y(x)=0$ is the only solution, as has been argued already in both the other answers and some of the comments as well.

But yes, the expression contains a derivative. So, strictly speaking, it's a differential equation.
And since the whole is equivalent with the equation $\,y=0$ , I'd say the degree of that ODE is **zero**.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the initial equation is only true for $y'=0=y$, there is no sense in computing degrees or orders.

Comment: its first order diff equation..

Comment: but still it is a differential equation..

Comment: According to you if a diff equation does not have solution then there is no meaning of order and degree?

Comment: Yes, formally it is first order and no, for the classification the existence of solutions is not important ($y\equiv 0$ is a solution). Degrees only apply to polynomials. Apart from that, everything is "wrong" with this differential equation.

Comment: if it is not a polynomial then it is converted to a polynomial...

Answer (score 1):

Your typographical picture is **not** a differential equation but a clumsy way of defining the function $x\mapsto y(x):\equiv0$. Neither the bounty nor the upvotes to the question, nor squaring, can improve this situation.

A *differential equation* is of the form $y'=f(x,y)$, or $F(x,y,y')=0$, and defines for each point $(x,y)$ of some **open set** $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ a slope $y'\in{\mathbb R}$ (maybe several admissible slopes). We then ask for the functions $x\mapsto y(x)$ that satisfy $y'(x)=f\bigl(x,y(x)\bigr)$, resp., $F\bigl(x,y(x),y'(x)\bigr)=0$  for all $x$ in the domain of $y(\cdot)$.