# Degree of the equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sin \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Find degree of $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\sin \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)$$

Since highest order derivative is $2$ and its power is one. Can we say degree is one.

Comment: Order 2 degree 1 as you said.

Comment: This is an order 2 differential equation, but the degree is not defined. See other postings [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117694/differential-equation-degree-doubt).

Comment: What is the degree good for? Never heard this kind of concept for differential equations. Does it have any use or is it just a definition.