# On the degree of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definition

In many texts I find the definition of the *degree* of an ODE saying:

1. the equation must be polynomial in the derivatives,
2. the degree is that of the highest order derivatives.

My question is if in 1., the function itself counts as a derivative (namely the zero$^{th}$ derivative).

E.g. $y''+e^{y'}=0$ is clearly not polynomial. But what about $y''+e^y=0$ ?

---

I am not asking about the *order*, and I know that rewriting the equation to polynomial form, if possible, is allowed.

Comment: There was a previous discussion (that I was a part of) on this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3576423/what-is-the-definition-of-the-degree, partially also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860401/degree-of-a-differential-equation. So depending on the point of view, your equations are not polynomial/algebraic in $y$, or they are of degree 1 in the highest derivative. The choice of what to use is personal by the author, there is no useful general concept.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: in a way it boils down to "is the zero$^{th}$ derivative a derivative ?" Is there any particular property of the equation/solutions that would differ between a power term $y^m$ vs. a general term $f(y)$ ? More generally, does a polynomial equation exhibit specific properties ?

Comment: In my opinion, there is only two relevant points-of-view, either everything is polynomial or at least algebraic, including the zeroth derivative, to apply ideas of differential algebra. Or only the highest derivative is polynomial, everything else is coefficient function, to get a controllable "multiple choice" vector field. There is something like Prince Khovanski's fewnominals theory and attempts to solve the Hilbert problem concerning the number of intersections of algebraic curves and trajectories of polynomial ODE where the degree, or the full monomial structure, plays a defining role.