# What is the application/use to know about the order and degree of a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A degree of a polynomial tells us the maximum number of possible roots of the equation.

But what is the use to know about the order and degree of the differential equation. Like, what does it **really** tell us about the equation we are working with?

For Example: If I am working with a polynomial of degree 3, and I tell that to you, you will be expecting, at most 3 roots of that polynomial. Degree of a polynomial only tells us about the number of roots, and so, x<sup>3</sup> and x<sup>3</sup> + 3x<sup>2</sup> + 5 both are equation of degree 3 and tells it will have a maximum of 3 roots.

But what does telling you that I am working with a differential equation of order 3 and degree 2 really tell you about the equation because you can not predict what the equation is, but then what can you predict with the data I give you?

I am new in the Journey of Differential Equations and wanted to know about the things (and reasons) that I am learning.

Thanks in advance for your answer. :)

Comment: An integral of the differential equation would give you back the original except for the constant. "Your" integrated polynomial will have up to four distinct roots and either 2 or 4 of these may be complex. Lacking the "constant", you may or may not be able to find these roots but you will know how many you can have. One help with your "solution" may be [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) that many of us use to verify tedious results or even simple ones.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x3+%2B+3x2+%2B+5+) is a sample of how you might use Wolfram Alpha for your polynomial, as a start towards solution.

Comment: @poetasis Thanks for your help, but I just wanted to give an analogy of degree in polynomial to degree in Differential Equation. I am asking that what does Order and Degree of a Differential Equation mean. And it seems that I'll have to wait a little more and learn more to really understand that. Anyways, thanks for your effort. :)

Comment: Differential equations are categorised depending on degree, order, ode/pde etc and so on. The method of solving ( standard steps,substitutions etc.) varies with each type.

Comment: Please don't put irrelevant tags. I don't see any connection to differential geometry here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order is a fundamental piece of information for a scalar ODE that tells you the dimension of the state vectors in the equivalent first order system. (For a system of higher order ODE you would want the sum of orders.)

The degree is a much more controversial idea, I'll refer to earlier answers of mine on this topic

- [What is the definition of the degree of a differential equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3577340/115115)
- [Degree of a differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2860432/115115)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, some of the things were too advanced foe me when I read them. But I hope within upcoming some time, I'll be able to understand what you really mean with it. Thanks again. :)