# Finding degree of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the degree of the equation $y(x) = e^{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

This is part of a larger question.

Now one of my books says that since $y(x)$ isn’t a polynomial the degree is not defined, but the answer is written as $1$

Which one is correct?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1117694/differential-equation-degree-doubt#:~:text=There%20exist%20a%20formula%20that%20allow%20you%20define,%E2%86%92%20%E2%88%9E%20log%20%7C%20f%20%28x%29%20%7C%20log) may help. I see a reason for the degree being equal to $1$, but the point is that the equations $e^{\frac{dy}{dx}} =y(x)$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} = \ln y(x)$ aren't considered equivalent differential equations when you see the link. If they were, then the degree would be $1$, but otherwise the LHS isn't a polynomial, so *my* take on this is that the degree is undefined.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon that is what I feel to

Comment: Go with what you feel. If someone is going to be evaluating any test on DE that you write, you can talk to them. My gut feel is that most people would think like I do, at least formally. Partly because the notion of degree doesn't really aid the process of finding the solutions, so classification as a process for these kind of DEs is kind of pointless. There would be better ways of classifying them e.g. by solution technique.

Answer (score -2):

The degree is 1 , note that first definition is indeed true that degree is defined only when all derivative terms are in polynomial form but if they are not then you try to transform the equation using manipulation and convert it into the said polynomial form.
Here it if you take natural log on both side you get dy/dx in polynomial form and since its exponent is 1 , the degree of this eq is 1.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that after taking log, why is it polynomial?